# XPath query for attribute value with a namespace

Tags: xml, xpath

I am working with an XML file with a namespace defined as `xmlns:abc="http:/abc.com"` and one of the attribute type value has namespace embedded, eg:

```
<der>
  <xyz xyztype="avg">2.5</xyz>
  <xyz xyztype="abc:totalcustomer">10</xyz>
</der>
```

I was able to figure out the xpath for "avg" type but having trouble with 2nd type.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: You should show your XML whole file, or at least a representative portion including the namespace declarations.  Also note that namespaces apply to attribute (and element) names, not values.

Comment: <a xlmns="http://123.com" xlmns:abc="http://abc.com> is namespace declaration followed by the schema i provided in the question. I have to figure out the xpath query to derive totalcustomer=10.

Comment: That's not well-formed XML, and that's not going to cut it for providing proper context for us to help you.  Again, please show your whole XML file or a properly representative portion of it.  Thank you.

Comment: Sorry its confidential data. when i use an xpath query like -  xyz[@xyztype='avg'] it get the proper result of 2.5 but doesn't work namespace prefixed values xyz[@xyztype='acs:totalcustomer']

Comment: If you can't put a representative sample of the input XML file (with 'secret1'->'x1', 'secret2'->'x2' if necessary), we can't help you.   The second `xyz` element in your posted XML can simply be selected by `/der/xyz[@xyztype='abc:totalcustomer']`, so if that's not working, you need to show more of your context for us to understand why.  Thanks.